# How to detect what type of change triggered a Jenkins project when started by Gitlab integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, integration, merge-request

I am trying to configure [Jenkins integration in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#configure-a-jenkins-integration-recommended), as it is recommended in favor of webhooks.

On the input form ([Gitlab project url]/-/integrations/jenkins/edit), I can check: **Merge request**, which has this note:

> Trigger event when a merge request is created, updated, or merged.

I would like to distinguish between merge requests being created or updated on one hand and being merged on the other hand. Only when they are being merged, I want Jenkins to perform a deployment.

Can I detect in Jenkins what type of merge request event triggered the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure this out with the variables the [Gitlab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables) exposes after the Webhook request. Here is the list of variables available.

```
gitlabBranch
gitlabSourceBranch
gitlabActionType
gitlabUserName
gitlabUserUsername
gitlabUserEmail
gitlabSourceRepoHomepage
gitlabSourceRepoName
gitlabSourceNamespace
gitlabSourceRepoURL
gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl
gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl
gitlabMergeRequestTitle
gitlabMergeRequestDescription
gitlabMergeRequestId
gitlabMergeRequestIid
gitlabMergeRequestState
gitlabMergedByUser
gitlabMergeRequestAssignee
gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit
gitlabMergeRequestTargetProjectId
gitlabTargetBranch
gitlabTargetRepoName
gitlabTargetNamespace
gitlabTargetRepoSshUrl
gitlabTargetRepoHttpUrl
gitlabBefore
gitlabAfter
gitlabTriggerPhrase
```